# Retrieving a particular attachment using IMAP

Tags: imap, attachment

For example if an email has multiple attachments as follows:

1. song.mp3    7 MB
2. guide.pdf   2 MB
3. image.jpg  60 KB

Is it possible to retrieve only the image attachment without downloading the whole email body using IMAP?

I can get a list of attachment filenames by using FETCH command on BODYSTRUCTURE but where do I go from there. The [RFC3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) does not explain how to retrieve specific body part.

Sadly, a lot of similar questions on SO are left unaswered. For those who has worked with IMAP before, could you share your solution regarding this matter?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. It's `FETCH BODY.PEEK[1.2.3]` where `1.2.3` is the part ID you determine through the `BODYSTRUCTURE`. See [page 56](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-56) of the RFC 3501.